# getElementsByTagName IE Issue

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

This code works well in all major browsers except Internet Explorer (Opera, Firefox, Crome..)

Every second js issue is related to IE. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(nesto,param)
{
var str = nesto;
    if (param == "latin")
    {
    str = str.replace(/Џ/g,"DŽ");
    str = str.replace(/Љ/g,"LJ");
    }
    if (param == "cirilic")
    {
    str = str.replace(/DŽ/g,"Џ");
    str = str.replace(/LJ/g,"Љ");
    }
return str;
}
function konvertor(param) {
 for (i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("jezik").length; i++) {
document.getElementsByName("jezik").item(i).innerHTML = myFunction(document.getElementsByName("jezik").item(i).innerHTML,param);
 }
}
</script>
<button onclick="konvertor('latin')">latinica</button>
<button onclick="konvertor('cirilic')">cirilica</button>
<div name="jezik">DŽ LJ</div>
<div name="jezik">DŽ LJ</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function konvertor(param) {
    var len=document.getElementsByName("jezik").length;
    for (i=0;i<len; i++) {
        // use array access instead of item()
        document.getElementsByName("jezik")[i].innerHTML = myFunction(document.getElementsByName("jezik")[i].innerHTML,param);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Man Programmer: IE supports the item()-method for nodeLists

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName fetches only elements by their name, when they `have a name-attribute(following the specification/DTD). Those are e.g. form-elements and images, but not <div>`-elements.

You may use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*[name='jezik']")
```

Comment: ok, but when i put getElementsById("jezik") and sett div to class to "jezik" it dont work on any browser :(

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("*[name='jezik']") also dont work on IE (my is 9)

Comment: can you please provide full code, maybe i miss something... please :)

Comment: sorry, i dont see, let me check